# Как сделать округлыми углы в TextArea как снаружи, так и внутри?

Tags: css3, html5

Здравствуйте.
Как можно сделать `TextArea` такого вида:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задай бордюр по шире и будет закругление и там и там:

```
TextArea {
  border: 10px solid #000;
  /* Для хороших браузеров */
  -moz-border-radius: 10px; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Safari, Chrome */
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* KHTML */
  border-radius: 10px; /* CSS3 */
  /* Для плохих IE */
  behavior: url(border-radius.htc); /* учим IE border-radius */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть очень удобный ресурс http://border-radius.com/ Просто задаешь какого радиуса округление, а он тебе сss генерирует. (не работает для ИЕ)